# How to proof a set of vectors a spanning set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Check whether the vectors $$(1,1,1),(1,2,3),(2,-1,1)$$ span the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ or not.

Comment: See if any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written in terms of these 3 vectors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**$$\det{\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1 & 2 & 3\\ 2& -1&1}}=5\neq0$$

Comment: Det is 5 .Then what?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that in general $n$ linearly independent vectors $\in \mathbb{R^n}$ are a basis and then span $\mathbb{R^n}$, to check that we can consider the matrix $A$ which has the vectors as columns or rows and use that the vectors are linearly independent if and only if

- $\det(A)\neq 0$ (usually effective for n small)
- RREF for $A$ contains $n$ pivots